# Having an issue reading a text file via console application?

Tags: c#

I have a program where I can load a database file and there's different items in it, and I am able to add more items to it. Previously on application close, the database file would not save.

However, I added a saveDb method where it actually saved the stock changes and in my text file, the results could be seen. But this broke my program entirely and now no matter what I do, it won't let me load text files anymore. I've rebuilt the project, reverted all the changes I made today, created new files, etc, but the **ONLY** way that my console app will now read and open a file is if its empty. I even temporarily completely removed all code to do with my save method.

```
public void LoadDb(string fname)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loading File {0}", fname);

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fname);
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadLine());
                inventories = new Inventory[count];

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    string[] line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    string name = line[0];
                    int code = Convert.ToInt32(line[1]);
                    string description = line[2];
                    int stock = Convert.ToInt32(line[3]);

                    inventories[i] = new Inventory(name, code, description, stock);
                }

                sr.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("{0} records loaded.", count);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not open file: ", exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT: I just solved it. I took out my item codes from the text file which is why it didn't want to read the file. I don't know how or when I managed to do that, but thanks a lot for the help.**

Comment: Your try/catch is giving a bad error message.  The first line of the text file must be a number so you do not get an exception on the line : int count = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadLine());  When an error occurs on this line the error will say : "Could not open file: "  You will get the same error if any of the Convert to integers fail.  I would and another try/catch in the code with different error message to indicate when a convert fails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first line of my text file is a number (the number reflects the amount of lines/items I have in my text file/database), but even with that I'm still getting an error

Comment: Could you paste a few lines of your file? Perhaps that could help identify the issue.

Comment: You are getting errors because what you are trying to convert to an integer is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your code to read the file using `File.ReadAllLines()` method (error handling etc. omitted for simplicity):

```
public static void LoadDb(string fname)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fname);
    inventories = new Inventory[lines.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] lineParts = lines[i].Split(',');

        string name = lineParts[0];
        int code = Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[1]);
        string description = lineParts[2];
        int stock = Convert.ToInt32(lineParts[3]);

        inventories[i] = new Inventory(name, code, description, stock);
    }
}
```

Here I assume your inventory file is something like

```
Name1,1,Desc1,100
Name2,2,Desc2,200
```

Note that this code assumes that there is no special data (like line count) in the first line; that is, the file contains only data *itself*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I will look into this, however I realised that the issue was with my text file